# Simple Salesforce how to create Custom Big Object?

Tags: metadata-api, python, big-object, simple-salesforce

Is there a way to create Custom Big Object with the simple salesforce metadata API?

This is my approach:

```
idx_field = mdapi.IndexField(
            name="MY_ACCOUNT_ID__c", sortDirection="DESC"
        )
      
idx = mdapi.Index(
            fullName="MyCustomIndex", label="My Custom Index", fields=[idx_field]
        )
custom_object = mdapi.CustomObject(
            fullName='test_account__b',
            label="test account",
            pluralLabel="test accounts",
            nameField=mdapi.CustomField(label="Name", type=mdapi.FieldType("Text")),
            deploymentStatus=mdapi.DeploymentStatus("Deployed"),
            enableSearch=True,
            enableReports=True,
            sharingModel=mdapi.SharingModel("ReadWrite"),
            fields=salesforce_fields,
        )
        
mdapi.CustomObject.create(custom_object)
```

But, when trying to create Custom Big Object I get this error: `FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, AllOrNoneHeader should be set to true to use CRUD-based calls with Big Objects`

I'm not sure how to set the Header to AllOrNone True.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to set metadataConnection.setAllOrNoneHeader(true) See [related](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_allornoneheader.htm)